# Unable to add attachment to ArcGIS Online feature service using Python and REST API

Tags: python, arcgis-online, attachments, request

I am attempting to use Python to add attachments to an ArcGIS Online hosted feature service, but I'm getting an 'Unable to add attachment to the feature.' message when I run the following code:

```
import requests 

objectId = '158'
attachUrl = "http://services.arcgis.com/abcdefg/FeatureServer/0/%s/addAttachment" %objectId
files = {'file': open('myAttachment.pdf', 'rb')}
params = { "token": token, "f": "json", "files": files}

r = requests.post(attachUrl, params)
r.text
```

The result:

```
u'{"error":{"code":400,"message":"","details":["Unable to add attachment to the feature."]}}'
```

I have verfied that I'm using a valud url,  objectID, and token.

I believe the issue is with the syntax I'm using to make the multipart post request, but I'm new to [requests.py](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and to programmatic file uploads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were very close!  This was quite tricky actually as the ArcGIS REST API documentation didn't explain much.  According to the [requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), you can explicitly set the content headers.  This worked for me:

```
import requests
import os
token = 'K6ZZZsf0Xtf...........PLNffN03fWcA..' 
url = 'http://yourserver/arcgis/rest/services/FRLK/FS_TESTING/FeatureServer/0'
attachment = r'L:\NEWP\failed\val\PIC_00001963.pdf'

def add_attachment(url, token, oid, attachment):
    att_url = '{}/{}/addAttachment'.format(url, oid)
    files = {'attachment': (os.path.basename(attachment), open(attachment, 'rb'), 'application/pdf')}
    params = {'token': token,'f': 'json'}
    r = requests.post(att_url, params, files=files)
    return r

f = add_attachment(url, token, 2402, attachment)
```

The real magic happens right here, which is what the REST API is looking for:

```
files = {'attachment': (os.path.basename(attachment), open(attachment, 'rb'), 'application/pdf')}
```

And the Fiddler response/webform:

[image]

Also, I have just added this functionality to my [restapi repository on GitHub](https://github.com/Bolton-and-Menk-GIS/restapi).  You can download this and use it to perform all kinds of operations against REST Services.

If you want to go this route, you can add attachments like this:

```
>>> import restapi
>>> usr = 'ursername'
>>> pw = 'password'
>>> url = 'http://yourserver.com/arcgis/rest/services/Folder/Some_featureService/FeatureServer/0'
>>> pts = restapi.FeatureLayer(url, usr, pw) # only need usr and pw if using token based authentication
>>> attach = r'O:\Pfdata\New Prague\Water\MK3-R012013AFB~files\MK3_00032946.jpg'
>>> r = pts.addAttachment(802, attach) # arguments are OID and path to attachment
{u'success': True, u'objectId': 2001}  #attachment has been succesfully added!
```

Comment: I edited my answer to include a link to my restapi repo on GitHub.  This provides a much easier interface.  Once you make a reference to a `FeatureLayer`, you can simply pass in an OID and path to an attachment when calling the `addAttachment` method.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very much for the help. I do my best to read the ArcGIS REST API docs, but found very little guidance. Your resapi repo is a much-needed resource; I'm looking forward to exploring it.

Comment: I agree, the help on adding attachments was not very useful.  I just happened to get lucky and find the Multi-Part Encoded file help in the requests documentation.  If you haven't used Fiddler, I would recommend it. Very useful for inspecting web traffic, especially when making calls with Python as there is no web interface.